# Simplify: $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a pretty hard problem:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}}$$
So it is a pretty long and complicated problem. I got stuck though. My idea was to turn $\sqrt[4]{27} =\sqrt[4]{3}\sqrt{3}$ and since I cant make the second part easier with Langranges formula (it doesn't apply to this) I made it $\sqrt[4]{3}-1$.
I seemed happy that I was getting somewhere and I thought that I had it but later on I just got stuck primarily by the 1's that I don't know what to do with.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by the conjugate?

Comment: @Huffman_Coding In which part? I never seemed to see an opportunity where it would help

Comment: what do you mean with solve?

Comment: Just to simplify as much as possible. The answer is $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: But the problem says: Prove that the number is irrational.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but you are using the word "solve" incorrectly in the title of your question. You can "solve" an equation (for a variable), or, more loosely, you can "solve" a problem, but you cannot "solve" an expression that represents a number. What is it exactly you want to do with that number? I guess you mean something like "simplify" maybe.

Comment: Edited. I meant simplify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$x=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}}$$

The square of numerator is $$2\sqrt[4]{27} -2\sqrt{\sqrt{27}-(\sqrt{3}-1)}=2\sqrt[4]{27}-2\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}$$

The square of denominator is $\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}$.

Hence $x^2 = 2$. Also note that $x>0$.

Comment: Wow... After doing all sorts of multiplying and division just to find out the answer is this simple... Thanks!

Comment: Dang!........... (Well, I deleted my answer... this just ... blew my answer out of the water.)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&=\frac{\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}-\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}\bigg)\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}\big)}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}\big)}\nonumber \\
&=\frac{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}-\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}\big)}\nonumber\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}+1}}\bigg(\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}\big)}\nonumber
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: It's times like this when you really appreciate MATHEMATICA or Maple...........lol